# .htaccess Url rewrite rule on wamp apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, yii, wampserver

I have a url in my application:

www.example.com/application/30201:1234

I hit this URL its throws an error.

Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /application/30204:1234 on this server.

Main config for rules is as follow:

`'rules'=>array(
    '<call:[0-9]+\:[0-9]+>( sip<sip:(\:[A-Za-z0-9]*@infocus\.net)+>)?( email<email:(\:[A-Z0-9a-z\._%\+\-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})+>)?'=>'user/index',
    '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
),`

I want to add rewrite rule in .htaccess which will redirect my application to user/index.

Comment: Can you show your Virtual Host definition for this domain. It should be in `\wamp\bin\apache\{apacheversion}\conf\extra\httpd-vhost.conf`

Comment: Application is not running on root. That is the problem

Comment: Well in that case create a Virtual Host which will give it its own DocumentRoot. Frameworks and CMS's always work better in a VH. See [this for some help creating a Virtual Host](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618)

Comment: I want apache to treat these numericals values as params:
www.example.com/application/30201:1234
And for this I have to change the .htaccess file. I tried the modrewrite with regex but they are not working.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in your .htaccess file when you hit the first url it will redirect to next url

```
Redirect /root_directory/first_url_path /root_directory/second_url_path
```

Comment: I want apache to treat these numericals values as params:
www.example.com/application/30201:1234